# python pandas how to expand dataframe by other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables, df1 and df2.

df1 is the sales list.

df2 is the combined product list.

I want to expand to df3 based on df1 and df2.

df3 is the sales list of individual products.

**df1**   (Can be imagined as a sales list)

[image]

**df2**  (Can be imagined as a combined product list)

[image]

**df3**  (Can be imagined as an individual product sales list)

[image]

**code:**

```
data1 = [["Banana", "1"],
        ["Apple", "2"],
        ["Milk", "3"],
        ["Banana_milk", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "1"],
        ["Watermelon_milk", "2"]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,columns=['Part_No','Quantity'])
print(df1)

data2 = [["Banana_milk", "Banana", "1"],
        ["Banana_milk",  "Milk", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "Apple", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "Milk", "1"],
        ["Watermelon_milk", "Watermelon", "2"],
        ["Watermelon_milk", "Milk", "1"]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=['Combination_Part_No', 'Part_No', 'Quantity'])
print(df2)
```

Comment: what is the logic of df3 creation?

Comment: Based on df1.
First see the banana, the banana does not appear in df2, then do nothing, and so on.

Comment: Apple is same.
Milk is same.
Then look at "banana_milk", it appears in "Combination_Part_No" in df2, we need to accumulate the quantity to df1 according to "Part_No" of df2, and delete "banana_milk" in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join first, then replace missing values of `Part_No` from `df2` by `df1` values and multiple `Quantity` columns with [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html), last aggregate `sum`:

```
df1['Quantity'] = df1['Quantity'].astype(int)
df2['Quantity'] = df2['Quantity'].astype(int)


df = df1.merge(df2, 
               left_on='Part_No', 
               right_on='Combination_Part_No',
               how='left')
df['Part_No'] = df['Part_No_y'].fillna(df['Part_No_x'])
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity_y'].mul(df['Quantity_x'], fill_value=1).astype(int)
print (df)
         Part_No_x  Quantity_x Combination_Part_No   Part_No_y  Quantity_y  \
0           Banana           1                 NaN         NaN         NaN   
1            Apple           2                 NaN         NaN         NaN   
2             Milk           3                 NaN         NaN         NaN   
3      Banana_milk           1         Banana_milk      Banana         1.0   
4      Banana_milk           1         Banana_milk        Milk         1.0   
5       Apple_milk           1          Apple_milk       Apple         1.0   
6       Apple_milk           1          Apple_milk        Milk         1.0   
7  Watermelon_milk           2     Watermelon_milk  Watermelon         2.0   
8  Watermelon_milk           2     Watermelon_milk        Milk         1.0   

      Part_No  Quantity  
0      Banana         1  
1       Apple         2  
2        Milk         3  
3      Banana         1  
4        Milk         1  
5       Apple         1  
6        Milk         1  
7  Watermelon         4  
8        Milk         2
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('Part_No', as_index=False)['Quantity'].sum()
print (df)
      Part_No  Quantity
0       Apple         3
1      Banana         2
2        Milk         7
3  Watermelon         4
```

Comment: Still accurate！！

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = [["Banana", "1"],
        ["Apple", "2"],
        ["Milk", "3"],
        ["Banana_milk", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "2"]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,columns=['Part_No','Quantity'])
display(df1)

data2 = [["Banana_milk", "Banana", "1"],
        ["Banana_milk",  "Milk", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "Apple", "1"],
        ["Apple_milk", "Milk", "1"]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=['Combination_Part_No', 'Part_No', 'Quantity'])
display(df2)
```

This is your data,I change `Apple_milk` to `2`, easy to debug.

```py
df1.Quantity = df1.Quantity.astype(int)
df2.Quantity = df2.Quantity.astype(int)

for line in df1.to_dict("records"):
    df2.loc[df2["Combination_Part_No"] == line["Part_No"], "Quantity"] *= line["Quantity"]

for line in df2.to_dict("records"):
    df1.loc[df1["Part_No"] == line["Part_No"], "Quantity"] *= line["Quantity"]

df3 = df1[df1.Part_No.isin(df2.Part_No)]
```

Then, `df3` is become

```
    Part_No Quantity
0   Banana  1
1   Apple   4
2   Milk    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone have a more concise way?

```
df1['Quantity'] = df1['Quantity'].astype(int)
df2['Quantity'] = df2['Quantity'].astype(int)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Part_No','Quantity'])

for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    if len(df2.loc[df2["Combination_Part_No"] == row["Part_No"]]) == 0:
        df3 = df3.append(row,ignore_index=True)
    else:
        df4 = df2.loc[df2["Combination_Part_No"] == row["Part_No"]][["Part_No","Quantity"]]
        df4["Quantity"] = df4["Quantity"] * row["Quantity"]
        df3 = df3.append(df4)
df3 = df3.groupby("Part_No",as_index=False).sum()
display(df3)
```

[image]